# How can I redirect a user to another page on React after state change and Google login?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Trying to redirect user to another page on react after state change/google login

Hi everyone, I am currently attempting to implement a google login button on my website, after which upon a successful login, the user will be redirected to my home page. I have managed to make the login button work and am able to get the user details, but am facing issues with the redirection. The tutorial that I followed for google login: https://livefiredev.com/in-depth-guide-sign-in-with-google-in-a-react-js-application/

I have tried using the useNavigate hook, and even through it appears to be wrapped in a  I am still getting the **useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a  component.** error.

Here is my code for App.js

```
import { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { GoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Locations from './pages/Locations';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import ViewMeetings from './pages/ViewMeetings';
import BookMeeting from './pages/BookMeeting';
import YourMeetings from './pages/YourMeetings';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar'


function App() {
  // Use this function to trigger the
  // "LogIn With Google" process
  // at the end of which the onSuccess function
  // is triggered
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="App">
    {window.location.pathname === '/login' && (
        <GoogleLogin onSuccess={credentialResponse => {
          console.log(credentialResponse);
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
          navigate('/home');
        }}
        onError={() => {
          console.log('Login Failed');
        }}
        />
      )}
      <NavBar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/locations" element={<Locations />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login  setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn}/>} />
        <Route path="/view-meetings" element={<ViewMeetings />} />
        <Route path="/book-meeting" element={<BookMeeting  />} />
        <Route path="/your-meetings" element={<YourMeetings />} />

      </Routes>
      
    
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

And this is my code for Home.js

```
import React from 'react';

function Home() {
    return (
        <div className='homepage'>
            <h1>You are now logged in</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

My index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="xxx">
      <App />
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

I would really appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The `App` component is rendering the router that provides the routing context that the `useNavigate` hook needs.

## Solution

Move `BrowserRouter` higher in the ReactTree so that it can provide a routing context to components below it.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="xxx">
      <Router> // <-- router wraps App, provides routing context
        <App />
      </Router>
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  // Use this function to trigger the "LogIn With Google" process
  // at the end of which the onSuccess function is triggered
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  const navigate = useNavigate(); // <-- can access routing context

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App">
        <GoogleLogin
          onSuccess={credentialResponse => {
            console.log(credentialResponse);
            setIsLoggedIn(true);
            navigate('/home');
          }}
          onError={() => {
            console.log('Login Failed');
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi, I dont really understand. I have updated my app.js and index.js in post body accordingly, but seem to be facing the same issue.

Comment: @Hong Have you tried applying the solution I suggest in my answer? `App` can't use the `useNavigate` hook because there's no routing context provided to it. The router needs to be rendered higher in the ReactTree. I've updated my answer to make this more overt.

Comment: Hi Drew, yup it works now. Thank you so much! From what I understand, because ```App``` is not wrapped within ```Router```, it is unable to reroute itself upon login? 

However, in my original code, when I add a navbar at the top of my page along with the routes, I am able to reroute accordingly (even though the login didnt work before I added your adjustments). Do you know why this is the case?

Thank you once again!

Comment: @Hong (1) Yes, that is *roughly* correct. (2) Yes, the `NavBar` worked as expected because it was rendered within the ReactTree created by the router component. In other words, there was a routing context provided to it from above.